# How to improve speed of list comprehension with array size 9e3?

Tags: python, performance, list, list-comprehension

I am multiplying an array Amp by another B**w where W is another array, and then summing the resultant array for each w.

Amp and B have size (4867206,1) and W has size (40x10^3,1).

This is currently taking 2min 49 seconds if W is size (1000,1). How can I improve this speed when using the complete W of size 40x10^3?

`Hw2=[np.einsum('i,i->', Amp, (np.array(B)**w)) for w in W]`

Comment: What is the shape of your desired output? `(1000, 4867206)`?

Comment: Try `Amp.squeeze() + B.squeeze() ** w`

Comment: What `dtype` is `W`?

Comment: Desired shape of output is the same size as W (40e3,1).

Comment: W is type float64. Happy to change if it will improve speed. Memory is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things which should give you a healthy speedup:

1) You don't want the `array` factory inside your list comp. It's actually quite slow.

2) Compute `log(B)` and then use `exp` instead of `**`. That saves *a lot*.

```
>>> Amp = np.random.random(4867206)
>>> B = np.random.random(4867206)
>>> W = 10 * np.random.random(40000) + 1
>>> 
>>> from time import perf_counter
>>> 
>>> t = perf_counter(); logB = np.log(B); s = perf_counter()
>>> s-t
0.1715415450744331
>>> 
>>> t = perf_counter(); [np.einsum('i,i->', Amp, B**w) for w in W[:40]]; s = perf_counter()
[232552.87174648093, 307130.7390907966, 411262.86511309125, 361323.4099230686, 254219.3700454278, 291692.2455839877, 324589.6747811661, 762459.3664474463, 224831.38520298406, 501641.86340860004, 466934.72400738456, 441544.52557156974, 995259.4253344169, 207811.00874071234, 408355.53573396447, 269901.94895861426, 304678.5850806002, 208719.98547583033, 318300.7763362345, 271688.90632957884, 388056.3735974982, 362437.1587603325, 456415.8506358219, 567634.1566253774, 418715.1493866043, 698332.545166694, 711861.6705545874, 391412.016841215, 569291.0132128834, 331811.20195587486, 898976.2873925611, 230896.99034275368, 225609.32356150646, 220438.15228011008, 526091.9360881918, 388536.063436256, 297158.4095318841, 382482.6531720307, 234679.1485575674, 263925.33778147714]
>>> s-t
15.207583270967007
>>> 
>>> t = perf_counter(); [np.einsum('i,i->', Amp, np.exp(w * logB)) for w in W[:40]]; s = perf_counter()
[232552.87174648093, 307130.7390907966, 411262.8651130912, 361323.4099230686, 254219.3700454278, 291692.2455839877, 324589.6747811661, 762459.3664474462, 224831.38520298406, 501641.86340860004, 466934.72400738456, 441544.52557156974, 995259.4253344169, 207811.00874071234, 408355.5357339644, 269901.9489586143, 304678.5850806002, 208719.98547583033, 318300.7763362345, 271688.90632957884, 388056.3735974982, 362437.1587603325, 456415.8506358219, 567634.1566253774, 418715.1493866043, 698332.545166694, 711861.6705545874, 391412.016841215, 569291.0132128834, 331811.20195587486, 898976.2873925611, 230896.99034275368, 225609.32356150646, 220438.15228011008, 526091.9360881918, 388536.063436256, 297158.4095318842, 382482.6531720308, 234679.1485575674, 263925.33778147714]
>>> s-t
5.111462005996145
```

Comment: Thank you Paul! It now runs 3 times faster.

Comment: Before I move on to Parallel processing, are there any other improvements?

Comment: @HarryWay Can't think of any.